# Populate laravel object with relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I want to populate Every `CustomerEvent` with the `Customer` related to the `CustomerEvent`.

When I Loop through the object and call to `$customerevent->customer` foreach object I can get the customer related to that event  but Can I populate the all objects in the main object without looping through every single event ?

I want to do something like this:

```
$typeOne = CustomerEvent::typeOne()->get();
$customersWithTypeOne = $typeOne->Customers;
```

Here my code:

**Table 1: "events"**

```
id, customer_id
```

**Model for Table 1 "CustomerEvent":**

```
<?php

class CustomerEvent extends Eloquent{
    protected   $guarded = ['id'];
    public      $table = "event";
    protected   $softDelete = true;

    public function scopeTypeOne($query)
    {
        $followUps = $query->where('type_id', '=', '1');
    }


    public function Customers()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Customer', 'customer_id');
    }
}
```

**Table 2: "customers"**

```
id
```

**Model for Table 2 "Customers":**

```
<?php class Customer extends BaseModel{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
}
```

**EventController:**

```
public function index()
{
    $typeOne = CustomerEvent::typeOne()->get();
    $customersWithTypeOne = $typeOne->Customers;
    dd($customersWithTypeOne);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you database scheme I see customer has many events, so I would recommend to define this relationship in you `Customer` model.

```
class Customer extends BaseModel{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function events()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('CustomerEvent', 'customer_id');
    }
}
```

Then you will be able to query customers with events:

```
$customersWithTypeOne = Customer::whereHas('events', function($query){
    $query->where('type_id', 1);
})->get()
```

Comment: I was actually using Laravel 4.0, So I had to upgrade to get this function. Thanks for the answer

Comment: $customers = Customer::whereHas('events', function($query){
   $query->typeOne();
  })->with('events')->get();

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Ardent can help you: https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent
It's an extension for Eloquent models and very popular.